# Booting stops at disk checking

Tags: 12.04, disk, tmp

I am constantly face this problem. When i start my laptop it checks the disk for errors , after that it shows , " some defects are found " when i press 'F' to Fix errors , it shows /tmp is not ready message . What i need to do to overcome this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Restart your machine. When you get to the grub screen press ESC and choose a "rescue mode" option. This will let you get into the system but / will be read only.

Then run your normal fixes. More then likely:

`fsck /`

Once it's done reboot. Everything should be back to normal. As a side note, if you need to remount the / as read write for some reason the command is:

`mount -o remount -w /`